# Вывод таблицы pandas в несколько строк

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Возник вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы таблица pandas сохранялась не в одну строку, а в несколько.

Вот мой код:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pet = ["Кот", "Собака", "Питон", "Попугай"]
array = np.array([[1,4], [3, 5]])
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Pet": [pet],
    "count": [array]
})
#Сохранение в Ексель
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pet.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

p.s Я знаю, что можно сделать так:

```
    "Pet": ["Кот", "Собака", "Питон", "Попугай"],
    "count": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Но хочу попробовать сделать через переменную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas DataFrame - это таблица. Соответственно, число элементов (строк) в каждом столбце должно быть одинаковым.

В ваших данных - `pet` - это список, состоящий из четырех элементов, а `array` - двумерная матрица, размерности 2x2. Чтобы составить таблицу из этих двух переменных, нужно сделать так, чтобы число элементов в каждом столбце было одинаковым. Например, можно "выровнять" матрицу `array` в одномерный список/вектор, состоящий из 4х элементов.

Пример:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Pet": pet,
    "count": array.ravel() # "вытягиваем" матрицу в одномерный вектор
})
```

результат:

```
In [94]: df
Out[94]:
       Pet  count
0      Кот      1
1   Собака      4
2    Питон      3
3  Попугай      5
```

Comment: ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length - выводит такую ошибку

Comment: @АртемГолубев, можете привести в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример данных?

Comment: Всё заработало. Для справки - в переменной pet я убрал попугаев, поэтому и была ошибка